# Entity Framework - Switch database while using the same dependency injection object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.2

at my workplace there are database that are generated everyday. The database name are generated with the current date such as "DB190716" , "DB190717", etc.. but still the database schema is the same. There are times that I need to make a report based on date range meaning I have to query multiple databases.

I used dependency injection for my database context in my repository. My question is there a way to keep using the injected database context but I can switch the database to the one I want?

I want to **avoid** the "using" method **(var dbContext = new DbContext())** so basically I want to achieve something like this:-

```
private readonly IDbContext _dbContext;
public MyRepo(IDbContext dbContext)
{
    _dbContext = dbContext;
}

public void MyFunction()
{
    var db1 = _dbContext.Change("DB190716");
    var db2 = _dbContext.Change("DB190717");

    var tableFromDb1 = db1.Table1; // table1 from db1 
    var tableFromDb2 = db2.Table1; // table1 from db2
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid creating a new DbContext? Seems to me you legitimately have a new and distinct database context in this scenario.

Comment: Because I like my codes clean and easy to maintain. I have a lot of services inside my project. Making a new instance of database context directly inside of each services makes me feel unconformable. If there are really no solution, then I have no choice.

Comment: A clean solution would map objects onto logical concepts rather than obscuring them. In this case, the logical concept is a distinct database context, so it is appropriate to instantiate a new object for it, as this is the clearest way to convey what is actually happening. If you want things more contained, perhaps you could write an injectable DbContextFactory that can be responsible for creating and returning these contexts.